# setup webpack config in nextJS (next.config.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js, export-to-excel

I'm working with NextJS and using [react-data-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export) plugin to generate xls files.
in the description it says :

> This library uses [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) and [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) and using
> [json-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader) will do the magic for you.
>
> ```
> ///webpack.config.js
> vendor: [
>         .....
>         'xlsx',
>         'file-saver'
> ],
> .....
> node: {fs: 'empty'},
> externals: [
>     {'./cptable': 'var cptable'},
>     {'./jszip': 'jszip'}
>  ]
> ```

but I have no idea how to implement it and got error like this :

```
The static directory has been deprecated in favor of the public directory. https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/static-dir-deprecated
Defining routes from exportPathMap
event - compiled successfully
> Ready on http://localhost:80 or http://localhost 
> Ready on https://localhost:443 or https://localhost 
event - build page: /menu_accounting/ReportGross
wait  - compiling...
error - ./node_modules/react-export-excel/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/ahmadb/repos/lorry-erp/node_modules/react-export-excel/node_modules/xlsx'
Could not find files for /menu_accounting/ReportGross in .next/build-manifest.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution for me was this:

1. Install this packages (if you installed, ignored this)

> npm install file-saver --save

> npm install xlsx

> npm install --save-dev json-loader

2. Add this to your ***nextjs.config.js***

```
    const path = require('path')

    module.exports = {
      ...

      //Add this lines
      webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
        // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
        if (!isServer) {
          config.node = {
            fs: 'empty'
          }
        }
    
        return config
      }
    
    }
```